# Configurating transaction manager when client and actual application are in different containers?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jboss, transactions

I have a third party application deployed in JBoss5.Third party application has provided us a **AppClient.java** class through which we can connect to it by instantiating and passing some connection proerties to it . Third party application takes some data and saves into database.

Now i have written a stand alone java class to connect to Thirdparty application and start the transactions as below.

```
         InitialContext initialContext = appClientReference.getInitialContext();


        tx = (UserTransaction)initialContext.lookup("UserTransaction");

        //Begin transaction
        tx.begin();

        //do some db operations by calling third party logic

        // Commit results
        tx.commit();
```

Now i would like to remove the stand alone program and create a web application and deploy into **Tomcat**. So, **my application will be in Tomcat and Third party applicatio is in JBoss**. Now how can i start the transactions? I am using spring3. **can i use any Spring configurations**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always create your appClientReference instance using a spring bean.

```
<bean id="demoLookup"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="cache" value="true" />
        <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="true" />
        <property name="proxyInterface" value="your fully qualified look up business interface" />
        <property name="jndiName" >
            <value>contextName/ejbName/remote or local </value>  // assuming you have not over ridden the default naming strategy.
        </property>
        <property name="jndiEnvironment">
             <props>
               <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory</prop>
               <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">jnp://localhost:1099</prop>
               <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces</prop>
             </props>
       </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Laurent, Thank you so much for your answer. But appClientReference does not have any interface. It has only class. How can i do now?

Comment: <bean id="..." class="..."> then set the values required. If you need a constructor use  <constructor-arg> . I would recommend you to read the spring documentation, it is very well explained there how to create beans, manage your configuration, and so much more : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/beans.html

Comment: Laurent, the question that i have is, in the answer above u mentioned <property name="proxyInterface" value="your fully qualified look up business interface" />. But appClientReference does not have any interface and it has only class.

Comment: Sorry that's an old documentation for the latest one check : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-definition

Comment: In that case, you cannot use the code i have given, you will simply want to instantiate your bean as a standard class then wire it (@autowire) or just use the same code you already have if spring is getting too complicated for a simple matter.